# How can I show the number of page only from the second page in TCPDF

Tags: footer, tcpdf

How can I showing the number of pages only from the second page in tcpdf?

How can I center de number of pages?

I use this class

```
private $customFooterText = "";

/**
 * @param string $customFooterText
 */
public function setCustomFooterText($customFooterText)
{
    $this->customFooterText = $customFooterText;
}

public function Footer()
{   

    // Linha 1
    $this->SetY(-16);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    $this->Cell(0, 10, $this->customFooterText, 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');


    // Números de página
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Pag '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!!

```
$pageN = TCPDF::PageNo();
    if($pageN == 1){
        //if page is 1... don't print anything
        return;
    }else{
        $this->Cell(0, 10, $this->getAliasNumPage(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
```